# Why doesn't `while i==50` do the same thing as `while i<=50`?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to print 1 to 50 but whenever I am use equals (`==`) instead of less than or equals (`<=`) it doesn't work. I can't find the reason that why it stops working.

```
i = 1

while i==50:
    print(i)
    i = i+1
```

It works when I use:

```
i = 1

while i<=50:
    print(i)
    i = i+1
```

Comment: `while i==50` is checking if `i equal to 50` then only the loop will run. But here `i  is 1` that why the loop is not running. In the second case `i <=50` that is true since `i is 1 and 1 is <=50`

Comment: _While `i` is equal to 50, do a thing_. i is 1, so i is not equal to 50. Do not do a thing.

Comment: I can't find a proper reason why you would expect a `while  i == 50` loop to execute when you just set `i = 1`? Think of `while` like a repeated `if`!

Comment: Think about what the conditional is saying. `while i==50` is literally "While the variable `i` is equal to 50 do the contents of the loop. If `i` doesn't start at 50 then it won't do anything. `while i<=50` means: While i is less than or equal to 50 then do the loop contents. If `i` is greater than 50 it won't run.

Comment: Try different numbers instead of 50 and see what happens.

Comment: @Epsi95 , Thank you much ,I understood the problem

Comment: @Abid another option is `while i != 50` which is saying "While i is not equal to 50, iterate." Since you're positively incrementing i, this would also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it doesn't give an error it's because you're telling the code to run while i is 50, in the code snippet that you provided i will never equal 50 as you define it as 1 and then check if it's 50 so it will skip over the while loop, if you set i to 50 from the start that while loop will run once because i will only be 50 the first time you run it because you add 1 to i making it 51 and 51 is not 50